# How to remove a js file from one page before it load completely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a problem with my javascript include . The app is already developed using some old version of jquery. Now I am using some new version of jquery files that is making some problem . The error when I am including new file is this.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
```

I tried the noCOnflict solution . But it didn't work for me .

Found that if I remove the new .js file then rest of my php files are working perfectly. But new page is throwing some error.Both are depend .

So I thought of removing the js file based on url which I am rendering . Is it possible ? Because I tried but it is not removing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post specific questions that can be possibly answered and resolved by others - this question, as it stands is too broad and has no concrete information on plugins, jQuery version, no code snippets...

Comment: @ZathrusWriter sorry the old version of jquery is 1.7.2 and new version is 1.8.2. I am using modal window using 1.8 version and datepicker with 1.8 version

Answer (score 0):

`datepicker` is not part of jQuery, but part of jQuery UI. I bet if you include jQuery UI, that error and other errors will go away.

http://jqueryui.com/